# AutomationAnywhere + Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, rpa, automationanywhere

I have an "Invalid character error" while using JS script to extract mails from text that I cannot handle for last 2 days.

[image]

I am getting text from web application by using Object cloning and passing it to variable which i will later pass to JS script.

[image]
[image]

And of course my JS script which I checked and it works:

```
var args = WScript.Arguments;

var pattern = \w+@\w+.\w;
var result = /pattern/.exec(args);

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this ?

Comment: Hello sorry, for late answer but we had national holidays and I did not have an access to AAE. No it is not working when I'm using plain js to check if script is good it works, but when I am implementing it to AAE it throws me error like above.

Comment: Hope you enjoyed your holidays, with respect to javaScript code , may I know what .exec(args) does ?

Comment: Can you also tell me what is the value of $strResult$?

Comment: exec() is looking in string "args" if there is something what matches pattern.
In this case strResult is equal to:
John Doe,
Sr. Billing Analyst 
Department 1R3 Market Logistic
Location 007 US NYC Rosendale
1-525-677-7187
JRdoe@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First and foremost lets break this down it modules and debug them.**

.

**First Module: Object cloning**

Object Cloning is very good to build reliability and this reliability is acheived by careful selection of Properties and in your example you have selected Path,DOMXPath, HTML Tag
Its a good practice to identify the properties which are unique and therefore yield high accuracy and some of these properties depend on the context
For example in a login page some properties include:

Priority 1: **Path, HTML ID, InnerText**

Priority 2: **DOMXPath, HTMLValue**

You may chose to add properties that you think may be unique to your context

Does `strResult` give you the expected value ? If yes, lets proceed

**Second Module: Run Script**

Accepts 2 Parameters `$strResult$` and `$mail$`

> And of course my JS script which I checked and it works:

and you have confirmed the JS module also runs fine

---

If you have verified the results of the first 2 modules, I think there could be an Invalid character somewhere in the script, parameters, check the regular expressions used. Shouldn't the pattern be enclosed in string `" "` ??

=====================

**EDIT:**

I wanted to recreate the issue and give you the desired result but I do not know your intended input and output for Javascript. However to the best of my understanding of your javascript, I have compiled and executed this script in Automation Anywhere and works perfect.

**JavaScript**

```
var args = WScript.Arguments;

if (args.length > 0)
{  
    var val=0;
     var str=args.item(0);
    var ary = str.split(",");
    //WScript.Echo(ary.length);

    // for loop in case there are multiple parameters passed
     for (var i=0; i < ary.length; i++)
     {


            //Takes the input passed as parameter
            var input = (ary[i]);

            // Uses the Match() Method to look for an email address in input string
            var result = input.match(/\w+@\w+\.com/); 

            //returns the email address
     }

  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**OR**

```
        //Takes the input passed as parameter
        var input = (ary[i]);

        //Declares the pattern used
        var pattern = /\w+@\w+\.com/

        // Uses the Exec() Method to look for a match
        var result = pattern.exec(input); 

        //returns the email address
```

**Run Script**

[image]

**Input Parameter**

[image]

**Output Parameter**

[image]

Comment: I am getting whole value by Object cloning correctly. I think there is a problem with passing variables to JS script, I have same problems with VBS. I mean when i hardcode script it works fine, but when I am trying to pass there any variable from/via AAE it throws me an errors. :/

Comment: Clint it's amazing how much work, time you have dedicated to explain me how it work's instead of typing just an answer "Try this <code>" Problem that I was facing all the time was that I was passing string to JS and I thought     /*var input = WScript.Arguments*/ will return me whole string in JS. Instead it returned me single word, so I had to create loop to put all the words into string. 
Once again I appreciate your work here ! All the best for YOU !

Comment: @Piotr any time, glad I could be of help, even I was able to learn by trying to solve your issue